# In Intellij CE, how do I get the maven tab to show up?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

This is my intellij version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-192.6262.58, built on August 20, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.39 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.2
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 725M
Cores: 6
Registry: 
Non-Bundled Plugins:
```

I just installed this, created a new java project, and added a pom.xml file at the root of my project.

I'm used to having a tab on the side for Maven, but I'm unable to find it:

[image]

When I look at my plugins, I see the Maven plugin is installed: [image]

How do I get a Maven "Tool Window" to show up?  I feel like in previous versions of intellij, it was always there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Maven toolwindow is shown if your project is associated with Maven. If IntelliJ IDEA doesn't see your project as a Maven project, right-click your root pom.xml file and select "Add as Maven Project" from the context menu.